# EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2) on [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa

Since iOS 5.1 I'm getting `EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=2)` errors when I instantiate an NSDateFormatter object.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; // bad_access
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd.MM.yyyy"];
```

[image]

Did anyone experience something similar or maybe even has a solution? It's making me crazy!
I'm using ARC for my project.

EDIT:

Even `NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];` is giving me the same error.

Comment: Your system looks completely broken.  There is nothing wrong with the code as far as I can tell...

Comment: Thanks for you answer. What do you mean by system?

Comment: Whatever this code is running on.  Unless there is something special about the context of this code, the system is broken in some way.

Comment: ok ... i think this is going to be a bad day :-(

Comment: Who votes this stuff up? There's clearly something wrong in Max's setup. Though bad for him it's not a helpful question for anybody else—at least with as few information as currently given.

Comment: Are you running on the main thread? Are you using ARC? Do you have NSZombieEnabled turned on? (It's in the "Edit Scheme" dialog, "Run" section, "Diagnostics" tab.) Can you post the entire code for the method that contains the problem line?

Comment: try the old clean, delete build folder, reinstall X-code, restart machine and then run. Or you could just give us some more code to work with and you'll avoid that whole malarkey

Comment: Try turning on malloc debug.  It looks like your memory allocation is running into trouble.

Answer (score 5):

I've had some similar problems some time ago. Ordinary 100%-error-free line causes this EXC_BAD_ACCESS, code=2, zombies show nothing. 
The thing was that I had a death cycle, somehow calling `function A` caused calling `function A` again, that caused calling `function A` again and so on (at the stack trace there were a looooot of lines). So I've just ran out of memory and got EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Preventing code to enter that death loop solved that for me.

Hope this helps.