# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when executing an arm blx rx

Tags: c, arm, clang, lldb, thumb

Here is the c-source code line which crashes on an armv7:

```
ret = fnPtr (param1, param2);
```

In the debugger, fnPtr has an address of 0x04216c00.  When I disassemble at the pc where it's pointing at the statement above, here is what I get:

```
0x18918e:  movw   r0, #0x73c
0x189192:  movt   r0, #0x1
0x189196:  add    r0, r2
0x189198:  ldr    r0, [r0]
0x18919a:  str    r0, [sp, #0x20]
0x18919c:  ldr    r0, [sp, #0x20]
0x18919e:  ldr    r1, [sp, #0x28]
0x1891a0:  ldr    r2, [sp, #0x2c]
0x1891a2:  str    r0, [sp, #0x14]
0x1891a4:  mov    r0, r1
0x1891a6:  mov    r1, r2
0x1891a8:  ldr    r2, [sp, #0x14]
0x1891aa:  blx    r2
```

Now, when I disassemble the memory at address $r2 (=0x4216c00), I get what is seemingly valid code that should be executed without any problem:

```
(lldb) disassemble -s 0x4216c00 -C 10
   0x4216c00:  push   {r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
   0x4216c04:  add    r7, sp, #0xc
   0x4216c08:  push   {r8, r10, r11}
   0x4216c0c:  vpush  {d8, d9, d10, d11, d12, d13, d14, d15}
   0x4216c10:  sub    r7, r7, #0x280
   0x4216c14:  mov    r6, r0
   0x4216c18:  bx     r1
   0x4216c1c:  add    r7, r7, #0x280
```

Yet what really happens is this:

EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x4216c00)

Can anyone explain what is wrong and why the address is considered illegal?

Full disclosure: I am no assembly expert.  The code compiled and linked is all c-code.  Compiler is clang.

Comment: What does the stack look like? A quick look around suggests running out of stack through impossibly large allocations or runaway recursion can give this error in seemingly innocent code.

Comment: @Notlikethat: ok; this sounds plausible.  How can I figure this one out?  What constitutes "A quick look around".  'much appreciated!

Comment: @Notlikethat: So, I figured I would increase the memory partition for the app until I hear back from you.  (≈ a quick check if i'm running into low mem issues that i can't see).  I still crash with the same exception.

Comment: I don't know iOS so I just searched EXC_BAD_ACCESS to check it is the equivalent of SIGSEGV as I assumed. The suggestions of stack exhaustion e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9836251/3156750) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/327082/3156750) caught my eye, since it's the sort of situation where you can end up with all kinds of weirdness. Dumping a stack trace at the point of the crash might be informative. Of course, it may still be something else like trying to call a freed object - just because the memory is still mapped doesn't mean it's still executable.

Comment: It might be good to try to reproduce the issue in C and share it. If it is a stack corruption it can be somewhere else before where you get bitten. Are you doing something fancy with function pointers and varargs, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Check the value of `r2` before calling executing `blx` instruction. It might be odd, telling the cpu that address is in thumb mode however from the listing it looks like in arm mode.

Try forcing clang to only arm mode by `-mno-thumb` to test this.

Comment: $r2 =0x4216c00 ; 0x4216c00 mod 2 = 0.  The address is even

Comment: @user3342339 hmm.. that was a shot in the dark :) then I guess next thing is to see where `SP` points to. Can you add that one as well?

Comment: will do;  i will  also check that compiler flag and report the effect.  thx.

Comment: tried the -mno-thumb: no go.  I still get the bad access error.  Also, the stack pointer is sp = 0x00f00eb8 : even address.

Comment: Amusingly, only the `mov` and the `bx` give it away as ARM - all the other instructions in that block would be 32-bit Thumb-2 encodings. Anyway, in the mismatched-interworking case surely you'd expect an undefined instruction error rather than a memory fault, no?

Comment: @Notlikethat I am not sure I understand your comment.  Like I said, I am not an assembly guru or that familiar with the different variations in the ISA of the different ARM architectures.

Comment: @Notlikethat I just jumped into interworking issue because I saw a function pointer and guessing `mov r6, r0` shouldn't be 4 bytes on thumb.

Answer (score 1):

The EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception has two bits of data in it, the first is the "kern_return_t" number describing the access failure, and the second is the address accessed.  In your case the code is 2, which means (from /usr/include/mach/kern_return.h):

```
#define KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE         2
                /* Specified memory is valid, but does not permit the
                 * required forms of access.
                 */
```

Not sure why this is happening, sounds like you are trying to execute code that doesn't have the execute permission set.  What does:

```
(lldb) image lookup -va 0x4216c00
```

say?

BTW, the exception types are in /usr/include/mach/exception_types.h, and if the codes have machine specific meanings, those will be in, e.g. /usr/include/mach/i386/exception.h)  For ARM info you may have to look in the header in the Xcode SDK.

Comment: Thank you @Jim Ingham.  This is very helpful.  Indeed, I am trying to execute code that is created on the fly.  I would say more but I am NDA'ed.  Flushing the icache does not work and I am wondering if there is any legit, workaround.

Comment: I don't think iOS allows you to change permissions on a region from writable to executable, but you should really ask ADC about whether this is possible and if so how.